# How to plot the list of functions properly?

Tags: plotting, syntax

Consider the following list:

```
list[x_] = {x^2, x, x^3, Sqrt[x]};
```

I tried to plot this list:

```
Plot[list[x],{x,0,1}]
```

However, it shows the curves with the same color. Is it possible to make it work properly?

Comment: Use `Evaluate[list[x]]`.